# What would happen if equal parts of hydrochloric acid, mercury and methylene chloride were mixed?

Tags: mixtures

I was going through the archive of Real Life Comics (first time reader, enjoying it so far), and in [one of the comics](https://reallifecomics.com/comic.php?comic=title-850), the main character of the comic reveals he has ordered hydrochloric acid, methylene chloride and mercury from an online chemist, and then says he ordered them to "pour them together and see what he gets".

[image: Image of the main character ordering the aforementioned chemicals and what he plans on doing with them]

I assume mixing these chemicals is probably not a good idea, but what would happen when mixing them? Like, I don't expect anyone to try this out (though if you can or have done this, your experience is definitely valued), but based on the properties of these chemicals, what would be the likely outcome?

Comment: Pretty much nothing, actually. They wouldn't mix together - there would be three layers.

Comment: They probably picked things that would not react on purpose.  I could imagine the emergency/fire calls if they had written pool chlorine, gasoline and chromic acid and some readers took it the wrong way.